# What is the time complexity of sum in loop?

Tags: python, time-complexity

here is my code:

```
my_list.sort()
runningSum=0
for idx,query in enumerate(my_list):
    runningSum+=sum(my_list[:idx])
```

as i know :

sort is O(nlogn)

for  is O(n)

sum is O(n)

but total is how can I calculate the time complexity?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said sorting is `O(n log n)` (given an appropriate algorithm is used).
Then the for loop runs `n` times. In the first iteration there is only one operation, in the second loop there are two, in the third three and so on.
Therefore the computational effort can be described as the sum of the first `n` natural numbers:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (n* (n - 1)) / 2 = 0.5 * (n² - n) = O(n²)
```

The sum of the first `n` natural number can be calculated using the  [Gaussian summation formula](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/groups/tatami/handdemos/sum/).

The rules of big O notation dictate:

[image: Wikipedia: sum big-O notation]

See [Wikipedia for big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum)

Therefore the overall runtime will be:

```
O(n log n) + O(n²) = O(n²)
```

> Note: The algorithm you created is not the most efficient as you compute the same sum over and over again.